# How to calculate missing components of rotation matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse, transpose

Q=\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt3&1/\sqrt3&1/\sqrt3\\ Q21&Q22&Q23\\Q31&Q32&1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}

\sqrt

Answer (score 0):

$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&1\\
-2&1&1 \\
0 & -1& 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
has positive determinant ( I guess they want that ) and $AA^T$ is diagonal. That is, $A$ can be adjusted to give $Q;$ there is some diagonal matrix, call it $D,$ such that $DA = Q$

Or, you can negate the second row and interchange columns one and two. So, not just one answer to the original question.